# Quantum dots applications

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, education, nanoscience, quantum-dots

I wanna find some interesting project for my master thesis concerning quantum dots, meanwhile I'm learning open quantum dynamics (Markovian & non-Markovain). Is there some ideas to combine these in order to come up with interesting and useful project?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first point out that there are exist different types of quantum dot, which are suitable for different applications, see, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/582275/what-happens-to-an-electron-hole-in-a-quantum-dot-when-you-irradiate-it-with-pho/582293#582293). The subject is vast, and I will give only a few examples.

Thus, collodial quantum dots are valued for their optical properties, and are used in optical devices.

Quantum dots formed by the split-gate technique are used, e.g., as qubits (the famous Loss-DiVincenzo peoposal), but can also be used to construct various switching devices. In this context one may also want to read about QD Aharonov-Bohm interferometers.

There are also applications for quantum dots integrated in various materials - thus, an oscillating carbon nanotube may serve as a quantum dot, and thus work as an electromechanical transducer. There are many other proposals of this type in the field known as *nanomechanics*.